# How to check java version at linux (RedHat6)

Tags: java, linux

[image] I am trying to check what java version I have installed in my linux machine, I have tried:

```
which java
```

and I get:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

but when I type:

```
java -version
```

the console is returning nothing and getting stuck in a "java mode" , feels like the command called java and its waiting for my inputs, any thing I type then returns nothing... until I type crt+C it exits the mode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can use

> rpm -qi java

OR

> yum info "java"

For future Referenecs . You can try any of these commands.

> rpm -qi "package_name_without_quotes"

It gives information of installed package. To display information about one or more packages (glob expressions are valid here as well), use the following command :

> yum info "package_name_without quotes"

OR

> yum list "package_name_without_quotes"

OR

> yum --showduplicates list "package_name_without_quotes"

The yum info package_name command is similar to the **rpm -q --info package_name** command, but provides as additional information *the ID of the Yum repository the RPM package* is found in.

You can also query the Yum database for alternative and useful information about a package by using the following command :

> yumdb info "package_name_without_quotes"

This command provides additional information about a package, including the check sum of the package (and algorithm used to produce it, such as SHA-256), the command given on the command line that was invoked to install the package (if any), and the reason that the package is installed on the system.

Comment: this hows "package java is not installed", strange. when I type "which java" it found out the path for the java

Answer (score 12):

If your java version more than 1.6 then it should work

> java -version

if version is not installed it returns error message

Please share some snapshot so i can rectify it

Answer (score 0):

To check which version of Java is installed, follow this procedure:
-Open a Linux command prompt.
-Enter the command java -version.

-If Java version is installed on your system, you see a Java installed response. Check the version number in the message.

-If Java is not installed on your system, or the version of Java is earlier than 1.6, use the Linux Yellowdog Update, Modified (yum) utility to install a compatible version. If the 64-bit version of Java V1.6 is not installed, the installation does not complete successfully.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS88XH_1.6.1/iva/install_mils_linux_java.html